# Using regex to find data in between certain data

Tags: regex, ruby

I am having an extremely difficult time trying to understand why my regex is failing me at the moment. In ruby, I have a string that includes both a start and stop point, but yet I cannot grab the data in between them using regex.

```
finding_doc.to_s.include? finding_start
# => true
finding_doc.to_s.include? finding_stop
# => true
finding_doc.to_s[/(#{finding_start})(.*?)(#{finding_stop})/m]
# => nil
```

Is there any additional arguments to regex that I can provide for it to actually work? I've always seen this work for me up until now. If it has *both* the starting and ending points, shouldn't it be able to grab everything in between them?

It should be noted that `finding_start` appears before `finding_stop` in the `finding_doc` variable, as shown below:

```
[11] pry(#<RailsAppTest>)> finding_doc.to_s.index(finding_start)
=> 81252
[12] pry(#<RailsAppTest>)> finding_doc.to_s.index(finding_stop)
=> 192451
```

I should also note that the contents within `finding_start` and `finding_stop` contains a bunch of XML, so I'm not sure if any of this would have to do with anything.

**Solution Attempt #1**

```
[9] pry(#<RailsAppTest>)> finding_doc.to_s[/#{finding_start}(.*?)#{finding_stop}/m, 1]
=> nil
```

Comment: `finding_doc.to_s[/#{finding_start}(.*?)#{finding_stop}/m, 1]`

Comment: Getting the same `nil` response, @WiktorStribiżew. Doesn't make sense to me because `finding_start` occurs before `finding_stop` so I have no idea why that's happening.